# Can I insert content add-in from VSTO add-in

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-js, office-addins

I have created to separate add-ins for Excel. One is a VSTO add-in (C#) an the other one is a content add-in (JavaScript/HTML) that vizualises data in a certain way. I would like to be able to insert a new instance of the content add-in directly from my VSTO add-in. For instance by a button in the custom ribbon. Is that possible?

For now, the only way I have found for inserting the content add in is through the 'My Add-ins' in the insert-tab in the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. There is no API for that.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the Office dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: It's quiet hard to understand why this is not supported. It really limits the usability of these add-ins. Do you know if the elements in the gallery `OfficeExtensionsGallery2` have an id that can be executed? Like with `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("...")`.